# Qual a diferença de global e nonlocal no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

No Python, existem duas declarações que são utilizadas para referenciar variáveis externas ao escopo local: `global` e `nonlocal`.

- Qual a diferença entre as duas declarações?
- Quando utilizar cada uma?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O funcionamento de ambas as declarações é bem semelhante, o que muda é o escopo para cada qual faz referência. A declaração [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) sempre faz referência ao escopo global, isto é, o escopo do programa, em si, enquanto a [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) referencia o escopo local acima do escopo atual. Confuso? Vamos para um exemplo prático.

Consideremos uma função decoradora que apenas incrementa um contador sempre que uma função for decorada por ela e, sempre que a função decorada for executada, deve armazenar o horário atual em uma variável.

```
import time

# Define o contador de funções decoradas:
decorated_functions = 0

# Definição do decorador:
def decorator(function):

    # Incrementa o contador:
    decorated_functions += 1

    # Inicializa o horário da última chamada:
    last_call = None

    # Define a função de retorno:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # Exibe e atualiza o horário da última chamada:
        print("Última chamada:", last_call)
        last_call = time.time()

        # Chama a função decorada:
        function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

<sup>Veja executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8Gd4X6) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NWAm/0)</sup>

Graficamente, podemos desenhar os três escopos da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde o retângulo vermelho delimita o escopo global, o retângulo azul delimita o escopo da função decoradora e o retângulo verde o escopo local da função `wrapper`.

Ao executarmos o programa, obtemos a mensagem de erro na linha 10:

> *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'decorated_functions' referenced before assignment*

O erro se dá devido ao fato que estamos tentando incrementar o valor da variável `decorated_functions` dentro da função decoradora, mas esta variável não está definida para escrita neste escopo (azul). Visto que a variável está definido no escopo global (vermelho), podemos informar ao interpretador que ele deve buscar a referência para esta variável no escopo global fazendo:

```
global decorated_functions
```

Ficando assim:

```
import time

# Define o contador de funções decoradas:
decorated_functions = 0

# Definição do decorador:
def decorator(function):

    # Importa para o escopo local a variável global:
    global decorated_functions

    # Incrementa o contador:
    decorated_functions += 1

    # Inicializa o horário da última chamada:
    last_call = None

    # Define a função de retorno:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # Exibe e atualiza o horário da última chamada:
        print("Última chamada:", last_call)
        last_call = time.time()

        # Chama a função decorada:
        function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

<sup>Veja executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/L0deXs) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NWAr/0)</sup>

Desta forma, o erro na linha 10 é corrigido, mas se tentarmos executar o código novamente, teremos o seguinte erro na linha 22:

> *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_call' referenced before assignment*

Novamente, o erro se dá por estarmos tentando acessar uma variável que não pertence ao escopo. Aqui que mora a diferença entre a `global` e a `nonlocal`. Se tentarmos importar a variável `last_call` para o escopo utilizando `global`, o interpretador irá buscar a variável no escopo vermelho, dando um novo erro dizendo que a variável não está definida, justamente porque a variável `last_call` não foi definida no escopo vermelho, mas sim no azul. Para informar ao interpretador que, ao invés de buscar no escopo global, ele deve buscar pela referência à variável um escopo acima, utilizamos a declaração `nonlocal`, ficando:

```
import time

# Define o contador de funções decoradas:
decorated_functions = 0

# Definição do decorador:
def decorator(function):

    # Importa para o escopo local a variável global:
    global decorated_functions

    # Incrementa o contador:
    decorated_functions += 1

    # Inicializa o horário da última chamada:
    last_call = None

    # Define a função de retorno:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        # Importa para o escopo local a variável:
        nonlocal last_call

        # Exibe e atualiza o horário da última chamada:
        last_call = time.time()
        print("Última chamada:", last_call)

        # Chama a função decorada:
        function(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@decorator
def foo():
    print("Foo executada")

foo()
```

<sup>Veja executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/VH0W8Z) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NWAv/0)</sup>

Desta forma, o interpretador irá buscar pela definição da variável um escopo acima, escopo azul, fazendo com que o código execute sem erros.

**Quando utilizar cada uma?**

Como cada declaração faz referência a um escopo diferente, dependerá de onde sua variável está declarada. Se estiver no escopo global, utilize `global`; já se a variável for local, dentro de um escopo acima de onde irá utilizá-la, utilize `nonlocal`.

---

Para deixar claro a diferença, vejamos um exemplo bem hipotético:

```
x = 1

def foo():
    x = 2

    def bar():
        global x
        print("bar:", x)

    def baz():
        nonlocal x
        print("baz:", x)

    bar()
    baz()

foo()
```

Temos uma variável `x`, global, com valor 1 e uma variável `x`, local em `foo`, com valor 2. A função interna `bar` importa a variável do escopo global, com `global`, e a função `baz` importa a variável do escopo local de `foo`, com `nonlocal`, portanto a saída deste código será:

```
bar: 1
baz: 2
```

<sup>Veja executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/2g1a0i) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NWBy/0)</sup>

**Leitura adicional**

- [The global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)
- [The nonlocal statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement)
- [PEP 3104 -- Access to Names in Outer Scopes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/)