# Python - Problema com variável

Tags: python-3.x

Não sei onde estou errando, mas eu escrevi a seguinte linha de código:

```
#variaveis globais
fcfs = False
#commands

def fcfscheck():

    fcfs = not fcfs
```

Supostamente essa função deveria alternar o valor de `fcfs` entre true e false toda vez que fosse chamada, mas eu estou recebendo um erro:

> Unresolved reference 'fcfs'

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250362/5878

Comment: Isto é um conflito de nomes, você tem uma variável local com o mesmo nome de uma variável declarada no escopo global, troque o nome da variável sua e não terá mais conflito.

Answer (score 1):

Isto é um conflito de nomes, você tem uma variável local com o mesmo nome de uma variável declarada no escopo global, troque o nome de umas de suas variáveis e não terá mais conflito.

E como a variável local [tem precedência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25000042/5429980), logo não sera possível obter o valor de `fcfs` porque ela ainda não existe no escopo local da sua função, entretanto, se eu trocar o nome da sua variável local não haverá conflito, veja:

```
#variaveis globais
fcfs = False
#commands

def fcfscheck():
  outroNome = not fcfs
```

E se quiser referenciar sua variável global sem alterar o nome, faça o que foi sugerido nas outras respostas `global fcfs`, mas tente facilitar mais para quem for ler seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
def fcfscheck():
   global fcfs
   fcfs = not fcfs
```

É necessário indicar na função que você está querendo modificar a variável global.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar o global na variável para usar ela mesma dentro de uma função

```
#variaveis globais
fcfs = False
#commands

def fcfscheck():
    global fcfs
    fcfs = not fcfs
```

Uma dica bacana, não sei qual IDE você usa, no meu caso uso o VSCode com a extensão Pylint, ele indica esses erros facilmente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Neste caso específico, você tem razão, mas em python você pode usar no escopo mais restrito variáveis definidas no escopo mais amplo sem precisar declarar que são globais. O problema é que o código da pergunda usa o mesmo nome de variável.