# Por que a variável não é modificada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# VARIÁVEIS
variavel = 0


def valores():

    if ( variavel == 0):
        variavel = 100

    elif (variavel == 1):

        variavel = 200

    elif (variavel == 2):

        variavel = 300

    elif (variavel == 3):

        variavel = 400


valores()
```

Aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 25, in <module>
    valores()
  File "teste.py", line 9, in valores
    if ( variavel == 0):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variavel' referenced before assignment
```

Por que isso ocorre? A variável não era para ser global nesse caso?
Como resolver isso, de forma que eu tenha uma variável na qual preciso modificar e acessar através de várias funções?

Comment: Posso sugerir alterar o título para "como lidar com variáveis globais em Python"?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença de global e nonlocal no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250362/5878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para modificar uma variável você precisa definir ela como global ou recebe-lá como parâmetro.

```
variavel = 0

def valores():

    global variavel

    if (variavel == 0):
        variavel = 100

    elif (variavel == 1):
        variavel = 200


def texto():
    variavel = 'teste novo valor'


valores()
texto()
print(variavel)
```

Esse código permite que você altere o valor de "variavel" e troque para 100, porém o resultado do print será 100 e não 'teste novo valor' pois dentro da função texto, "variavel" é local.

Answer (score 5):

Se declarar que a variável é externa (global) funciona, mas não faça isto, se precisa trabalhar com um valor que vem de fora receba ele como parâmetro.

```
variavel = 0

def valores():
    global variavel
    if (variavel == 0):
        variavel = 100
    elif (variavel == 1):
        variavel = 200
    elif (variavel == 2):
        variavel = 300
    elif (variavel == 3):
        variavel = 400

valores()
```

Prefira fazer

```
def valores(variavel):
    if (variavel == 0):
        variavel = 100
    elif (variavel == 1):
        variavel = 200
    elif (variavel == 2):
        variavel = 300
    elif (variavel == 3):
        variavel = 400
    return variavel

variavel = 0
variavel = valores(variavel)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0qlqpc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bjwohhyw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Escope.py).

Comment: Sobre usar como parâmetro e reatribuir: Proteção contra concorrência? Elegância? Ou tem algo mais que eu não percebi?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Um dos pontos é manutenção. A variável não tem o valor alterado de forma *mágica* quando você analisa o fluxo do código.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado E também porque foi assim que ele fez. Em código real eu faria de um jeito bem diferente :)