# Erro na soma de código iniciando com 0; Problema ao inserir dados em arquivo.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como podem ver no código abaixo já tentei de diversas formas para fazer com que a cada produto inserido fosse criado um novo código com `codigo += 1`, porém está retornando:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'codigo' referenced before assignment!

Colocando essa linha como comentário e seguindo o código fico com um problema na inserção dos dados do produto digitado pelo usuário no `arquivo.txt`.

Já tentei com `for`, manualmente 1 por 1 e não estou conseguindo. Se adicionar 1 item apenas com o nome preenchido e com a quantidade, preços e total comentados adiciona normalmente, mas mais de 1 já retorna o erro do `except..`

Agradeço a atenção.

```
import time
arquivo = open('arquivo.txt','w')
quantidade = codigo = 0
produto = ""
preCompra = preVenda = total = 0


def menu():
    print("Digite a opção desejada: \n0. Sair do programa\n1. Adicionar produto\n2. Remover produto")
    opcao = int(input("Que opção você escolhe? "))
    if opcao < 0:
        print("Esta não é uma opção válida!")
    elif opcao == 0:
        print("Saindo do programa!")
        exit
    elif opcao == 1:
        addProduto()
    elif opcao == 2:
        print("Você escolheu a opção 2!")
    else:
        print("Você deve escolher um dos itens da lista!")


def addProduto():
    #codigo += 1
    produto = str(input("Qual o nome do produto? "))
    quantidade = int(input("Quantos produtos? "))
    preCompra = float(input("Qual o preço de compra? "))
    preVenda = float(input("Qual o preço de venda? "))
    total = float(preCompra * quantidade)
    produtosAdd = [produto, quantidade, preCompra, preVenda, total]
    try:
        '''for pro in produtosAdd:
            arquivo.writelines(produtosAdd)
        arquivo.close()'''
        arquivo.write(produtosAdd)
        print("Produto adicionado com sucesso!")
    except:
        print("Ocorreu um erro!\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    menu()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   menu()
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta pois o seu português estava muito confuso, caso eu tenha interpretado algo mal sinta-se á vontade para reeditar a pergunta.

Comment: Vinicius, no seu código comentado que insere no arquivo, você chamou o `arquivo.close`. Se fechar o arquivo, como espera adicionar mais dados nele?

Comment: Desculpa, foi uma falha após algumas tentativas, mas mesmo retirando o arquivo.close() do laço ou até mesmo comentando a linha, não funciona. O problema está em adicionar mais de uma variável ao mesmo tempo no arquivo. Obrigado Anderson.

Comment: Então faça o seguinte: edite a pergunta e coloque EXATAMENTE o código que você está executando e descreva o que está acontecendo, tal como descrever quais são os dados que seriam escritos no arquivo e o que, de fato, foi escrito.

Comment: Já foi editado.. Deveria ser escrito no documento as variáveis que estão dentro da variável produtosAdd, mas retorna o except.

Comment: Vinicius, não é uma boa você capturar a exceção desta forma e apresentar uma mensagem genérica. Você jamais saberá o que está errado. Busque capturar a exceção e exibir a mensagem da mesma.

Comment: Consegui! Obrigado pela ajuda Anderson! Estava tentando adicionar como dicionário, o qual não é permitido, no momento que converti para string, foi.. Abraço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variável `codigo` será global e é importada para o escopo da função como somente leitura. Se você precisa modificar o valor da mesma, precisa utilizar o termo `global` para importá-la como escrita também.

```
def addProduto():
    global codigo
    codigo += 1
    ...
```

Tratei um pouco sobre a definição de escopos nesta outra pergunta:

- [Qual a diferença de global e nonlocal no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250362/5878)

Comment: Obrigado, Anderson! Realmente para a parte do código resolveu, agora só sigo com o problema de adicionar os itens ao documento .txt