# Variável se transforma em string sem motivo

Tags: python

Fiz um programa onde deve-se adivinhar um número, e no final funciona normalmente, mas acabei me deparando com um acontecimento um tanto estranho.

No código eu transformo uma `string` com um número dentro, em um tipo `int`, porém a variável volta a ser do tipo `string` sem motivo algum.

O código é esse:

```
import random

lancar = 1

n_secreto = random.randint(1,20)
print(n_secreto)


def inicializar():

   print('Para sair digite "sair" ')
   return input("Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: ")


def valida_lancar(lancar):

    while lancar != int:

        if lancar == "s" :
            print("Jogo fechado")
            break

        else:
            try:
                # Aqui eu transformo em int
                lancar = int(lancar)
                print(type(lancar))
                break

            except ValueError:
                print()
                print(f"{lancar} Não é um input válido!")
                lancar = input("Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: ")


def testa_lancar(lancar):

    print(type(lancar))

    if lancar == n_secreto:
        print()
        print("Acertou")

    elif n_secreto != lancar and lancar != "s":
        print()
        print("Errou")

    else:
        lancar = "s"

while lancar != "s":

    lancar = inicializar()
    print(type(lancar))

    valida_lancar(lancar)

    # Ao chegar aqui a variável já é uma string novamente

    print(type(lancar))

    testa_lancar(lancar)
```

Colocando `testa_lancar(lancar)` após a chamada `valida_lancar(lancar)`, tudo funciona normalmente. Mas mesmo assim gostaria saber o porquê da variável virar `string` do nada.

Answer (score 6):

Considere o código abaixo:

```
lancar = 'abc'

def faz_algo(lancar):
    lancar = 1

faz_algo(lancar)
print(lancar) # aqui vai imprimir o que?
```

No seu entendimento, ele deveria imprimir `1`. Afinal, eu criei a variável `lancar` com o valor `'abc'`, e passei ela para a função `faz_algo`. Mas dentro da função eu setei o valor dela para `1`, então depois que a função executa, o valor dela deveria ser `1`, certo?

**Errado**. O código acima imprime "abc" ([pode conferir](https://ideone.com/ZkWDCk)).

---

Para entender o que acontece, tem uma série de conceitos a serem entendidos. Vou dar uma explicação mais "simplista" e tentar ser didático sem me prender a muitos termos técnicos, e nem entrar em detalhes de implementação do Python (mas colocarei alguns links para você se aprofundar no assunto). A ideia é entender de forma geral o que está acontecendo.

Primeiro, basta pensar que a variável `lancar` criada fora da função **não** é a mesma variável `lancar` que foi declarada como parâmetro da função. Elas por acaso têm o mesmo nome, mas isso é circunstancial, afinal, você poderia chamar a função de outras maneiras, sem precisar criar a variável `lancar`:

```
# sem usar variável
faz_algo('abc')

# usando variável com outro nome
x = 'abc'
faz_algo(x)

# usando uma outra função que retorna algum valor
faz_algo(outra_funcao()) # assumindo que outra_funcao() retorne alguma coisa
```

Ou seja, o valor que é passado para a função é copiado para o parâmetro `lancar`, e o que acontece lá dentro não interfere na variável `lancar` do lado de fora (caso ela exista, porque nos exemplos acima ela nem existe, e isso não impede que a função execute mesmo assim).

Ou seja, quando eu faço `faz_algo(lancar)`, o que acontece é mais ou menos o seguinte:

- o valor da variável `lancar` (a externa, que foi criada fora da função) é passado para a função `faz_algo`
- esse valor é copiado para o parâmetro `lancar`
- mesmo se dentro da função eu atribuir outro valor a `lancar`, só estou mudando a "versão interna" dele (a que existe dentro da função), sem interferir na variável `lancar` externa

<sup>*Como eu disse, é uma explicação simplificada e sem se apegar à terminologia correta para todas as coisas, nem aos detalhes internos de implementação da linguagem.*</sup>

Basicamente, é por isso que você está tendo este comportamento no seu código. Dentro da função você converte o parâmetro `lancar` para `int`, mas a variável externa continua sendo `string` (ela não é afetada pelo que acontece dentro da função, já que não é a mesma variável - elas só tem o mesmo nome, mas uma só existe dentro da função e a outra só existe fora).

---

#### Toda regra tem exceções

Claro que dá para acessar a variável externa (que nesse caso chamamos de "global") dentro da função, como já explicou [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/442119/112052). E claro que há casos em que é possível alterar os dados dentro da função, bastando que o tipo seja mutável (como uma lista, por exemplo):

```
def muda_lista(lista):
    lista.append(3)

x = [1, 2]
muda_lista(x)
print(x) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Mas isso não funciona da mesma maneira se atribuirmos outro valor à lista:

```
def muda_lista(lista):
    lista = [1, 2, 3]

x = [1, 2]
muda_lista(x)
print(x) # [1, 2]
```

Bom, mas talvez eu já esteja confundindo mais do que ajudando. Deixe esse exemplo das listas de lado e vamos voltar ao seu caso.

---

Existem dois conceitos que você deve entender: passagem por valor e passagem por referência. De forma **bem** resumida, quando você passa parâmetros para uma função, você pode passar somente os valores, e a função recebe uma cópia dos mesmos, e tudo que ela fizer lá dentro não interfere nos valores de fora (isso é a passagem por valor). E na passagem por referência, é possível alterar o valor dentro da função. Para se aprofundar no assunto, eu sugiro começar [por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437/112052) (a pergunta tem exemplos em Java e C#, mas serve para entender a ideia geral do conceito).

Quanto ao Python, há quem defenda que ele não tem passagem por valor nem por referência, e sim um "terceiro tipo" de passagem de parâmetros. Não vou entrar no mérito de discutir a terminologia correta (a documentação chama de "[*pass by assignment*](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)"), mas você pode ler [aqui](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) e [aqui](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html) (independente da terminologia, esses links são interessantes para entender melhor o funcionamento). De qualquer forma, para se aprofundar nos detalhes da linguagem, sugiro ler também o [*Data Model* da mesma](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

---

Dito isso, já sabemos o problema do seu código, que é assumir que a variável externa poderia ser alterada dentro da função, apenas passando-a como parâmetro. Tem outros problemas também, que é - na minha opinião - complicar à toa o algoritmo (talvez nem precisasse quebrar em tantas funções), além de depender do tipo da variável (e não do seu valor) para determinar ações do programa.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/442124/112052) já deu uma versão bem simplificada do seu código, para você ver como não precisava ter complicado tanto. Só queria acrescentar mais alguns detalhes.

Uma mensagem do seu código diz: `Para sair digite "sair"`. Mas no código você verifica se foi digitado somente "s". Então já ficou inconsistente, pois se for digitado "sair", ele não sairá do programa. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/442119/112052) sugeria usar `startswith` ([antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/442119/13), agora foi corrigido), mas isso não é uma boa solução porque o programa vai aceitar **qualquer texto** que comece com "s" (ou seja, se for digitado "sapo", "s   abc 123" e qualquer outra coisa que comece com "s", ele sai do programa), e não parece ser bem o que você quer.

Uma outra opção seria:

```
import random
import sys

segredo = random.randint(1,20)
print(segredo)

def get_palpite():
    try:
        print('Para sair, digite "sair"')
        entrada = input("Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: ")
        if entrada == 'sair':
            print("Jogo fechado")
            sys.exit() # sai do programa

        # não foi digitado "sair", tenta converter para número
        palpite = int(entrada)
        if 1 <= palpite <= 20:
            return palpite
        else: print(f'Erro: o número deve estar entre 1 e 20 e você digitou {palpite}')
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Erro: '{entrada}' não é um número")

while True:
    if get_palpite() == segredo:
        print("Acertou!")
    else:
        print("Errou!")
```

No caso, `if entrada == 'sair'` só sai do programa se for digitado exatamente "sair". Se quer aceitar também "SAIR", "Sair" e outras combinações de maiúsculas e minúsculas, pode usar:

```
if entrada.lower() == 'sair':
```

Se quiser aceitar tanto "sair" quanto apenas "s", pode trocar para:

```
if entrada in ('sair', 's'):
```

Ou ainda (caso queira aceitar "S", "Sair", "SAIR", etc):

```
if entrada.lower() in ('sair', 's'):
```

Também verifiquei os valores do palpite antes de retorná-lo (se não for um número, ou se for mas não estiver entre 1 e 20, já peço para digitar novamente).

Comment: Era isso que eu queria que o @JeanExtreme002 tivesse explicado, mas ele não me deu ouvidos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu entendi onde está o erro da minha resposta, só que não sei nem como editar minha resposta pois o hkotsubo já respondeu em detalhes e como eu disse, não sei muito sobre esse assunto. Estou em um dilema entre apagar ou não minha resposta porque não é como se ela estivesse 100% errada, além de que apagando a resposta, seria apagados os comentários com suas explicações com o assunto de passagem de valor e de referência.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 aquela explicação era uma orientação para você melhorar a resposta, outro dia vi que você ficou chateado por tomar uns downvotes. Mas os comentários foram tipo um presente é **seu** e você faz o uso que quiser, depois que o emiti eu não controlo mais o destino .

Comment: Okay então, vou tentar editar.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais nada, eu gostaria de falar que na programação, nada acontece do nada como se fosse mágica. Se algo não ocorreu como o esperado, significa que houve um [bug](https://www.bluecore.com.br/desenvolvimento/o-que-sao-os-bugs-nos-softwares) causado por algum programador. Dito isto, vamos entender o que acontece no seu código :)

Talvez você pense que ao passar a variável `lancar` na chamada da função, a referência dela também será passada. Sendo assim você conseguiria manipulá-la dentro da função não é mesmo... mas você está errado!

Quando você passa uma variável na chamada de uma função, o que você na verdade está fazendo é apenas passando o valor da variável.

Para que você possa entender melhor, se tivermos uma variável **x** com o valor `7`, apenas o número `7` seria passado para a função e não a variável em si. Exemplo:

```
# Abaixo o parâmetro "n" não recebe a referência da  
# sua variável, mas sim o valor dela.

def func(n): 
    print(n)

x = 7
func(x)
```

> *Espera um pouco... Se o parâmetro da função recebe apenas uma cópia, porque eu consigo alterar uma lista ou outros objetos criados fora da função de dentro da função?*

Bom isso acontece porque ao passar a lista ou outro objeto como parâmetro, você está passando o endereço de memória daquele objeto. Resumindo, o parâmetro da função não receberia o objeto em si mas sim a referência do **objeto** e não da variável como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443427/157404) explicou.

```
def func(lista):

    # Alterou o objeto fora da função pois "lista" faz referência ao objeto criado.
    lista.append(5) 

    # Não altera o objeto pois aqui a "lista" perde a referência do 
    # objeto anterior e passa a ter um endereço novo.
    lista = [1, 2, 3]

lista = [7, 8, 9]

func(lista)
print(lista) # [7, 8, 9, 5]
```

Uma analogia que acabei de criar é a seguinte:

> Imagine que você possui uma gaveta (variável) que guarda ferramentas (valor) e você quer utilizar essas ferramentas no seu trabalho. Ao invés de você levar a gaveta junto com as ferramentas, você apenas leva as ferramentas.
>
> Dessa forma você não pode pintar, destruir ou fazer qualquer outra coisa com a gaveta, você pode apenas manipular as ferramentas que a gaveta guardava.

Podemos dizer então que a variável `lancar` dentro da função é nada mais nada menos do que uma cópia da variável fora da função, sendo que ambas não possuem ligação alguma.

> *Isso significa que eu não posso manipular a variável fora da função de dentro da função ?*

É claro que você **pode** e nós vamos fazer isso! Aguenta aí e leia a próxima parte da resposta :)

---

Uma outra coisa que você deve saber é que a variável `lancar` dentro e fora da sua função, são diferentes não só pelo motivo anterior, mas também porque elas estão em [escopos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250362/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-global-e-nonlocal-no-python) diferentes!

Enquanto uma está no escopo *global* a outra está no escopo *local*. Logo, a sua função não altera a variável que está fora, ela apenas altera a variável que está dentro.

Veja esse simples exemplo abaixo:

```
n = 0

def muda():
    n = 1
    print("Dentro:", n) # Dentro: 1

muda()
print("Fora:", n) # Fora: 0
```

Para alterar a variável fora da função, você deve utilizar a declaração [`global`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword), para dizer ao Python que você deseja utilizar a variável do escopo *global* (escopo fora da função).

Seguindo o exemplo acima, o código ficaria assim:

```
n = 0

def muda():
    global n # Diz ao Python que quer usar a variável fora da função

    n = 1
    print("Dentro:", n) # Dentro: 1

muda()
print("Fora:", n) # Fora: 1
```

O problema é que no seu código, você não pode simplesmente adicionar o `global` à sua função. Isso porque a sua função, já recebe o parâmetro `lancar` que possui o mesmo nome da sua variável global (isso gera um conflito).

O que você deve fazer neste caso, é retornar o novo valor de `lancar` criado dentro da função com um `return`, ou então remover o parâmetro de sua função (o que eu não recomendo).

Veja como ficaria seu código:

**Utilizando a declaração "global":**

```
def valida_lancar():
    global lancar

    # Código ...

valida_lancar()
```

**Utilizando o "return":**

```
def valida_lancar(lancar):

    # Código ...

    return lancar

lancar = valida_lancar(lancar)
```

Para dar um fim a esse assunto de escopos, uma coisa bastante interessante que também podemos ver, é que assim como não podemos manipular uma variável no escopo global sem utilizar a declaração `global`, também não podemos ter acesso a variáveis criadas dentro da função.

Isso porque todas as variáveis criadas dentro da função, morrem na função. Veja:

```
def func():
    n = 15

func()
print(n) 

# Gera um erro porque "n" não existe fora da função. 
# A variável "n" morreu após a função ser encerrada.
```

---

Um outro problema no seu código que eu pude notar foi na condicional abaixo:

```
while lancar != int:
```

Por enquanto, essa condicional não afeta o seu programa pois ela não é necessária já que você utiliza o `break` caso o `if` seja verdadeiro ou não seja gerado uma exceção dentro do bloco `try`.

O problema é que caso você escreva mais código e eventualmente precise dessa condicional, ela não vai funcionar como deveria.

Isso porque você verifica se o valor de `lancar` é igual ao tipo `int`. Talvez a condição que você queira seja essa:

```
while type(lancar) != int:
```

---

Além dos problemas que citei acima, há um outro problema quanto a opção de sair. Você informa ao usuário que para sair, ele deve digitar `"sair"`, porém isso não funciona já que no código você verifica se o que ele digitou foi `"s"`.

Para consertar o problema, atualize a informação no `print()` ou utilize um operador de comparação para verificar se a entrada do usuário é igual a `"sair"`. Exemplo:

```
if lancar.lower() == "sair":
    # Código ...
```

---

Como eu tive muito tempo sobrando hoje, eu dei uma refatorada no seu código. Diminuí as funções e as renomeie para ficarem mais coesas, consertei os bugs, etc.

Espero que goste e continue se aprimorando :)

```
import random

def imprime_resultado(jogada, n_sorteado):

    print("\nAcertou!\n") if jogada == n_sorteado else print("\nErrou!\n")

def obter_jogada():

    print('Para sair digite "sair" ')
    return input("Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: ")

def valida_jogada(jogada):
   
    try: return True if 1 <= int(jogada) <= 20 else False
    except: return False

while True:
    
    n_sorteado = random.randint(1, 20)
    jogada = obter_jogada()

    if jogada.lower() == "sair": break
    
    if valida_jogada(jogada):
        imprime_resultado(jogada, n_sorteado)
        
    else:
        print(f'\n"{jogada}" não é uma entrada válida!\n')
```

Comment: Essa explicação `Primeiro de tudo, você deve saber que a variável lançar dentro da função e fora da sua função, são diferentes! Essas duas variáveis são diferentes, pois estão em escopos diferentes e não possuem ligação alguma.`. Sim elas são diferente mas não explica o que realmente acontece. O AP está tentando passar uma variável por referência e deveria ser ensinado que a linguagem Python não suporta passagem de parâmetros por referência.

Comment: Pode ser que sim como pode ser que não. Python foi minha primeira linguagem e eu também não sabia que não se pode alterar uma variável em outro escopo assim como eu também não sabia sobre variáveis de referência. E quanto a não explicar o que realmente acontece, eu deixei linkado na parte de `escopos` uma resposta que explicar melhor isso.

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento em muitas linguagens, então posso acabar interpretando "passagem de parâmetros por referência" de uma forma equivocada, mas mesmo assim vou perguntar. Como assim Python não suporta ? Claro que não é possível passar referência de variáveis de tipo primitivo, mas é possível sim passar de objetos.

Comment: Em python a passagem é feita por atribuição o que significa é passado para função ou método sempre uma referência, mesmo o tipo sendo primitivo ou não, porém essa referência é passada por valor. Se passar um objeto mutável por atribuição você vai poder mexer nas propriedades e métodos e as referências externas serão impactadas mas se criar um novo objeto dentro e tentar substituir no parâmetro da atribuição há uma dissociação e o parâmetro da função aponta para o novo objeto e as referencias externas estarão dissociadas...

Comment: ... Se passar um objeto imutável por atribuição, que é esse caso, automaticamente a atribuição estará dissociado de quaisquer referências externas então uma alteração na atribuição ou referência externa passa batida. A resposta que lincou é boa, mas não é o caso da questão

Comment: Resumindo, eu altero o objeto mas não altero a variável em si. Entendi, obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Obrigado por você ter perguntado e se interessado pelo assunto.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Há quem defenda que o Python não tem passagem por valor nem por referência, e sim um "terceiro tipo" (ideia defendida [aqui](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) e [aqui](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html)). De qualquer forma, Jean, a sua resposta fala de variável local criada dentro da função, que não é a mesma coisa que um parâmetro passado para a mesma (uma diferença sutil, porém importante para o caso da pergunta).

Comment: @hkotsubo foi o que eu disse, o mecanismo chama-se **Passagem por Atribuição**. É um modelo hybrido onde a referência é passada por valor.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Ah tá, é que nos artigos que eu vi eles usam outros nomes (porque não parece haver consenso sobre o nome exato do mecanismo)

Comment: @hkotsubo, O termo em inglês é [`Pass by Assignment`](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) que traduzi como "Passagem por Atribuição".

Comment: @AugustoVasques Nossa, eu não tinha encontrado isso na documentação. Vou atualizar minha resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Eu já entendi que não se trata de escopo e coloquei lá em cima com a explicação. Não tão bem detalhada como a do hkotsubo, mas acho que expliquei corretamente e ainda com uma pequena analogia. Tem certeza que leu tudo ?

Comment: Gostaria que pudessem reavaliar a resposta, obrigado.

Comment: Melhorou @JeanExtreme002. Mas como disse já tinha lhe dado o positivo, então vai depender dos outros votantes.

Comment: Uma analogia melhor que a gaveta: tenho um papel com coisas escritas. Ao chamar a função, ela tira uma cópia e eu fico com a original. A função pode rabiscar a cópia à vontade que a original permanece intacta. Mas no caso de listas, imagine que no papel tem o endereço onde moro e a função manda entregar algo nesse endereço. Não importa se ela tem a original ou a cópia, a entrega será feita no mesmo lugar. Mais ou menos isso...

Answer (score -2):

Acontece que a função `input()` retorna uma variável do tipo `str` e isso precisa ser tratado/convertido adequadamente para evitar esse tipo de confusão.

Simplificando a sua ideia:

```
import random

segredo = random.randint(1,20)
print(segredo)

while True:
    try:
        # A funcao input() sempre retorna str
        entrada = input("Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: ")

        # Comparacao de string
        if entrada == 's':
            print("Jogo fechado")
            break

        # Conversao de str para int
        # Se nao for possivel, lança
        # uma exceção do tipo ValueError
        palpite = int(entrada)

        # Comparacao do palpite com o segredo
        if palpite == segredo:
            print("Acertou!")
        else:
            print("Errou!")

    except ValueError:
        print(f"Erro: '{entrada}' Nao eh um input valido!")
```

Possível Saída:

```
6
Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: 3
Errou!
Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: 5
Errou!
Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: 6
Acertou!
Digite um número entre 1 e 20 para jogar: s
Jogo fechado
```

Comment: Tenho certeza que ele sabe que o `input()` retorna uma string e sua resposta não explica o porquê do valor da variável permanecer uma string.

Comment: Complexidade de código também pode ser um problema! Minha resposta foi elaborada levando em consideração a [PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). A complexidade do código apresentado é suficiente para confundir o autor da pergunta a ponto dele não conseguir depura-lo!

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 e Lacobus , Eu dei o upvote para os dois pois ambos estão certos e ambos estão errados. Primeiro upvote foi por conta do algoritmo do AP ser espaguete e sua devida estruturação precisa ser abordada. O segundo upvote foi por conta da identificação da dissociação entre a variável global e o parâmetro, embora Jean o conceito que usou para identificar a dissociação esteja equivocado então na sua resposta vou deixar uma orientação.