# Como passar valores de uma função para outra?

Tags: python, funções, return

Fiz o código abaixo, com o intuito de receber e exibir dados, como se estes fossem referentes a uma nota fiscal. O código apresenta o seguinte erro ao ser executado:

```
File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    imprimir_nota()
  File "main.py", line 41, in imprimir_nota
    print ('\nCliente: {}'. format (Nome))
NameError: name 'Nome' is not defined
```

Se eu estiver certo e não houver um grande erro na minha lógica em relação ao código, o problema é a ausência de um retorno de valores das duas primeiras funções para a terceira. Tentei fazer a correção, quando imaginei isso, mas não consegui, muito provável que devido a minha falta de compreensão sobre como executar direito.

```
def dados_cliente():
Nome = str (input ('Por gentileza, informe o nome do cliente: '))
CPF = int (input ('Por gentileza, informe o CPF do cliente: '))
Celular = int (input ('Por gentileza, informe o celular: '))

def dados_peça():
    peca1 = 823556
    peca2 = 632552
    peca3 = 445568
    peca4 = 550632
    peca5 = 785642

Numero_Peca = str (input ('\n\nPor gentileza, informe o número da peça: '))

if Numero_Peca == peca1:
  Descricao_Peca = str ('Peça de motor para motocicleta Yamanha.')
  Preco = 100.0

elif Numero_Peca == peca2:
  Descricao_Peca = str ('Peça de motor para carro Honda.')
  Preco = 170.0

elif Numero_Peca == peca3:
  Descricao_Peca = str ('Peça de rolamento Yamaha.')
  Preco = 257.99

elif Numero_Peca == peca4:
  Descricao_Peca = str ('Peça de aceleração Dafra.')
  Preco = 55.80

elif Numero_Peca == peca5:
  Descricao_Peca = str ('Peça de frenagem Honda.')
  Preco = 145.98

Qtd_Peca = int (input ('Por gentileza, informe a quantidade desejada: '))

def imprimir_nota():
    print ('\n\n..::NOTA FISCAL::..')
    print ('LOJA DE PEÇAS EM GERAL')
    print ('CNPJ: 40.769.710/0001-03')
    print ('\nCliente: {}'. format (Nome))
    print ('CPF: {}'. format (CPF))
    print ('Telefone Celular: {}'. format (Celular))

    print ('Quantidade do produto: {}    Código do produto: {}    Descrição do produto: {}    Preço unitário: {}'. format (Qtd_Peca, Numero_Peca, Descricao_Peca, Preco))

   dados_cliente()
   dados_peça()
   imprimir_nota()
```

Comment: Pesquise por "parâmetros" de funções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, quando você faz isso:

```
def dados_cliente():
    Nome = str (input ('Por gentileza, informe o nome do cliente: '))
```

A variável `Nome` é local à função `dados_cliente`, e não pode ser acessada de fora da função (existe uma explicação mais detalhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443427/112052)).

Uma opção para corrigir isso é fazer com que a função retorne esses dados. Por exemplo, as 3 informações poderiam ser retornadas em uma tupla, e quem chamar a função pode obter o retorno e guardar em variáveis:

```
def dados_cliente():
    nome = input('Por gentileza, informe o nome do cliente: ')
    cpf = input('Por gentileza, informe o CPF do cliente: ')
    celular = input('Por gentileza, informe o celular: ')
    # função retorna os dados em uma tupla
    return (nome, cpf, celular)

# chamar a função e obter o retorno, já separado em variáveis
nome, cpf, celular = dados_cliente()

# ou obter tudo em uma tupla
# nesse caso, dados[0] é o nome, dados[1] é o CPF e dados[2] é o celular
dados = dados_cliente()
```

Repare algumas mudanças: [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string então é redundante fazer `str(input())`. E o CPF não é um número (no sentido de ser um valor numérico com o qual posso fazer cálculos, etc), [ele é uma informação que por acaso usa dígitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/112052) (em documentos isso faz diferença porque muitos permitem zeros à esquerda, por exemplo, que sumiriam se você convertesse para número - sem contar outros documentos que permitem letras). Enfim, por isso removi o `int` do CPF. O mesmo vale para o número de telefone ("0800" não é o mesmo que o número "800", pois retirar o zero da frente torna o telefone inválido, etc).

Enfim, uma vez obtido o retorno da função, você pode passá-lo como parâmetros para as demais funções. Tem outras coisas que dá para simplificar, ficaria assim:

```
def dados_cliente():
    nome = input('Por gentileza, informe o nome do cliente: ')
    cpf = input('Por gentileza, informe o CPF do cliente: ')
    celular = int(input('Por gentileza, informe o celular: '))
    return (nome, cpf, celular)

def dados_peça():
    pecas = { # cada número de peça é mapeado para uma tupla com a descrição e preço
      823556: ('Peça de motor para motocicleta Yamanha.', 100.0),
      632552: ('Peça de motor para carro Honda.', 170.0),
      445568: ('Peça de rolamento Yamaha.', 257.99),
      550632: ('Peça de aceleração Dafra.', 55.8),
      785642: ('Peça de frenagem Honda.', 145.98)
    }

    while True: # faz um loop, enquanto não for digitado um número de peça válido
        numero_peca = int(input('\n\nPor gentileza, informe o número da peça: '))
        if numero_peca in pecas:
            descricao, preco = pecas[numero_peca]
            break # sai do while True
        else:
            print(f'Peça {numero_peca} não existe, digite novamente')

    qtd_peca = int(input('Por gentileza, informe a quantidade desejada: '))
    return (qtd_peca, numero_peca, descricao, preco)

# função recebe como parâmetros as tuplas retornadas pelas 2 funções acima
def imprimir_nota(cliente, peca):
    print('\n\n..::NOTA FISCAL::..')
    print('LOJA DE PEÇAS EM GERAL')
    print('CNPJ: 40.769.710/0001-03')
    print('\nCliente: {}'.format(cliente[0]))
    print('CPF: {}'.format(cliente[1]))
    print('Telefone Celular: {}'.format(cliente[2]))

    # eu também poderia fazer format(peca[0], peca[1], peca[2], peca[3]) em vez de format(*peca)
    # coloquei :.2f no preço para sempre imprimir com 2 casas decimais
    print('Quantidade do produto: {}    Código do produto: {}    Descrição do produto: {}    Preço unitário: {:.2f}'.format(*peca))

cliente = dados_cliente() # obter os dados retornados pela função
peca = dados_peça() # obter os dados retornados pela função

# passar os dados obtidos pelas funções anteriores para a função imprimir_nota
imprimir_nota(cliente, peca)
```

Comment: Uau, obrigado! Foi MUITO esclarecedor, e de quebra ainda consegui aprender coisas novas. Vlw!