# Como utilzar o retorno de uma função em outra função Python

Tags: python, funções

Sou novo em Python e não estou conseguindo utilizar um retorno de uma função em outra função na sequência:

Estou colocando um exemplo fictício apenas para descrever minha dúvida:

```
def calcular_velocidade(distancia, tempo):
    velocidade = distancia / tempo
    return velocidade

def calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, tempo):
    aceleracao = velocidade / tempo
    return aceleracao

calcular_velocidade(20, 2)
calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, 2)
```

Como faço para utilizar o valor da variável `velocidade` da função `calcular_velocidade` no lugar do parâmetro `velocidade` da função `calcular_aceleracao` ?

Comment: Detalhe, na primeira função vc poderia colocar simplesmente `return distancia / tempo`. Se a variável `velocidade` não vai ser usada para mais nada e só vai ser retornada, ela é desnecessária. O mesmo vale para `aceleracao` na segunda função.

Comment: @hkotsubo bem observado! Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

É bem simples, basta chamar a função `calcular_velocidade` como parâmetro da função `calcular_aceleracao`:

```
calcular_aceleracao( calcular_velocidade(20, 2) , 2)
```

Seu exemplo, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
def calcular_velocidade(distancia, tempo):
  velocidade = distancia / tempo
  return velocidade

def calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, tempo):
  aceleracao = velocidade / tempo
  return aceleracao

aceleracao = calcular_aceleracao(calcular_velocidade(20, 2), 2)

print(aceleracao)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/CompleteGrownDaemons

---

Também é possível declarar uma variável e assim, armazenar o retorno da função `calcular_velocidade`, utilizando então a variável declarada como argumento para a função `calcular_aceleracao`:

```
velocidade = calcular_velocidade(20, 2)
aceleracao = calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, 2)
```

Ficando então da seguinte forma:

```
def calcular_velocidade(distancia, tempo):
  velocidade = distancia / tempo
  return velocidade

def calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, tempo):
  aceleracao = velocidade / tempo
  return aceleracao

velocidade = calcular_velocidade(20, 2)
aceleracao = calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, 2)

print(aceleracao)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/CraftyTrustworthyDehardwarization

---

Perceba que o resultado é exatamente o mesmo, são formas diferentes de trabalhar. Caso você precise utilizar o resultado de `calcular_velocidade` mais de uma vez, declarar a variável pode ser uma opção melhor pare evitar chamadas da mesma função.

Comment: Daniel muito obrigado pela explicação muito clara e com riqueza de informações. Espero que sua explicação chege a outros colegas de TI que possam ter a mesma dúvida. Abs.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer isso, não basta criar uma variável dentro da função, já que você estaria criando uma variável local e não global (veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250363/157404) que fala sobre o assunto).

Para utilizar o retorno da função dentro da chamada de outra função, você deve criar uma variável que recebe o retorno da primeira função para ser usada na chamada da segunda função.

Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
def calcular_velocidade(distancia, tempo):
    velocidade = distancia / tempo
    return velocidade

def calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, tempo):
    aceleracao = velocidade / tempo
    return aceleracao

velocidade = calcular_velocidade(20, 2)
calcular_aceleracao(velocidade, 2)
```

---

Uma outra forma que não é assim tão recomendada já que algumas vezes pode deixar seu código bagunçado e difícil de ler, é chamando a primeira função dentro da chamada da segunda função.

```
# Perceba como ficou um pouco mais difícil de ler o código.
calcular_aceleracao(calcular_velocidade(20, 2), 2)
```

Comment: Jean muito obrigado pela ajuda! Excelente explicações que poderão ajudar diversos colegas em TI.